# Cannot rebuild a service after docker-compose with mongo volume is built

Tags: mongodb, docker, permissions, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file like this:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    container_name: us_mongodb
    environment:
     ...
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-dev-volume:/data/db


  mongo-express:
  ...


  example-app:
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: "./example-app/Dockerfile"
      args:
        - PORT=4200
    container_name: us_example-app_builder_and_server
    ports:
      - 4200:4200 

volumes:
  mongo-dev-volume:
```

(The example app dockerfile is just a simple static fileserver, which copies a file to itself.)

If I run the `docker-compose up` everything is fine.

I want to rebuild the said example application, so I run this command:

`docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --no-deps --build example-app`

And for that, I get the following error message:

```
forest@forest:~/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/Docker/prod-nginx$ docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --no-deps --build example-app
Building example-app
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
...
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 184, in rec_walk
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/Docker/prod-nginx/mongo-dev-volume/journal'
```

What is the problem here?

Things I have found out/tried already:
1.) The said service **has nothing related** to the mongodb volume. But if I delete the said mongo-dev-volume, then the command can run. After that, if a singe `docker-compose up` creates the said folder, and the problem still cames up. But that's not a solution to delete the db on every restart...

2.) I can still do `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up` without a problem (but as I said, I need to rebuild the said example app...)

3.) I tried adding a .dockerignore as saw in some other threads:

```
#.dockerignore
**/mongo-dev-volume
```

but it does not seem to have any effect whatsoever. (It's right next to the docker-compose.yml)

4.) I suspect that something will be related to permissions. But I do not create the volume (only bind the name), and docker creates it:

```
forest@forest:~/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/Docker/prod-nginx$ ls -lsh
total 32K

4,0K -rw-rw-r-- 1 forest forest 3,8K dec    5 10:31 docker-compose.yml
4,0K drwxrwxr-x 2 forest forest 4,0K júl    1 12:25 example-app
4,0K drwxrwxr-x 4    999 root   4,0K dec    5 13:12 mongo-dev-volume
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My kindof workaround was to remove the volume bind, and let Docker create a separate(ly handled) volume, outside the workdir.

Instead of this

```
  ./mongo-dev-volume:/data/db
```

I have entered this:

```
  mongo-dev-volume:/data/db
```

This way, I can still access the file, and as I understand it is better to let the OS and Docker handle this, instead of creating a filesys link inside the project.

Comment: where does this put it though?

Comment: It depends on the system. For linux, it's probably going tol be `/var/lib/docker/volumes/xyz`